# Flutter - How tap / touch area works?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget

1) If I have this, when I tap the child `Container` it doesn't print 'tap':

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => print('tap'),
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    ),
  ),
),
```

2) If I have this, when I tap the child `Container` it prints 'tap':

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => print('tap'),
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(),
    ),
  ),
),
```

3) If I have this, when I tap the child `Container`, outside the text, it prints 'tap':

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => print('tap'),
    child: Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Text("A"),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Can someone explain me these 3 behaviors?

Comment: Try these samples with behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,  of  GestureDetector

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, but I still don't understand why with the default behavior in  1) doesn't print 'tap', in 2) prints and in 3) prints when tapping outside the text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. A `Container` with bounds `(height and width)` is nothing but a placeholder for other widgets to go inside it. Since you haven't provided any `child` to it or any other property such as `color` or `decoration` to it, the `container` is considered to be invisible for `GestureDetector`.

According to the official [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) document, `by default a GestureDetector with an invisible child ignores touches. this behavior can be controlled with behavior.`

If you still want the placeholder `container` to be recognized as tap event, use `behavior` property of `GestureDetector`, that will tell GestureDetector to tap on the container and then you will see `tap` printed, as below:

```
Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: GestureDetector(
            behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
            onTap: () => print('tap'),
            child: Container(
              width: 100,
              height: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

2. In this case, since you provided `decoration` property and used `BoxDecoration()`, it renders a box based on the bounds provided by its parent widget. So, the `container` has a box shape. 
   In order to see how the box shape is rendered inside the container, just provide a `border` property, as below:

> ```
> Container(
>         color: Colors.red,
>         child: GestureDetector(
>           onTap: () => print('tap'),
>           child: Container(
>             width: 100,
>             height: 100,
>             decoration: BoxDecoration(
>               border: Border.all(color: Colors.yellow, width: 4)
>             ),
>           ),
> ```

[image]

You can see the `yellow` borders spanning entire `container` size, which acts as a layer on top of the `container` and now considered to be tappable. 
Hence, GestureDetector's tap is recognized and you see `tap` printed.

3. In this case, since you have provided `child` widget as `text`, `GestureDetector` identifies it since the widget is visible and hence `tap` is printed, irrespective of whether you tap on the text or outside of it, because since `GestureDetector` doesn't have a size by itself, it relies on child's size, which in this case is the `bounds` (height and width). Hence, it considers the entire bounded area to be tappable and you get the `tap` event printed anywhere inside it.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Excellent! I think is kind of confusing that in 3) the bounded area is considered tappable when in the 1) case it isn't, just for the fact that it has a child. It would be more obvious if in 3) the bounded area outside the text isn't tappable and you could make it tappable with the behavior property like in 1). I suppose it's done that way because the GestureDetector only knows its direct child.

Answer (score 0):

First understand that `GestureDetector` only detects tap on the area which is drawn by its `child`, ignoring behaviour set by it. Now let's take a look at your cases.

---

**Case 1: (Doesn't detect touch)**

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => print('tap'),
    child: Container( // child Container (has nothing to draw on screen)
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
    ),
  ),
),
```

The child `Container` isn't drawing anything on screen, so `GestureDetector` won't allow click. But you will say it has both `width` and `height`, yes you're right but it doesn't have anything to draw on screen.

If you give it any `color` or `decoration`, or any `child` it will have something to draw and thus it would be able to detect tap.

---

**Case 2 (Detects touch):**

```
Container( 
  color: Colors.red,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => print('tap'),
    child: Container( // child Container
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(), // has something to draw on screen
    ),
  ),
),
```

Here you are giving child `Container` a decoration so it has something to draw on screen, and `GestureDetector` would allow click.

---

**Case 3 (Detects touch):**

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => print('tap'),
    child: Container( // child Container 
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      child: Text("A"), // has something to draw on screen 
    ),
  ),
),
```

Here you are giving child `Container` a `Text`, and thus something to draw on screen and thus clicking is enabled.

Note: Not only `Text` but full area of child `Container` receives click because `GestureDetector` direct `child` is `Container` with `width` and `height` set to `100` and not just the `Text`.

Comment: Thanks, I still think the 3) case is confusing because the Container doesn't have anything drawn outside the Text and that part is tappable when in the 1) case isn't.

Comment: For case:3, if you use `color` property you'd see the `Container` is actually drawn on the screen. To verify you may use this child `Container` in `Column` and put something below  it, you'd see the new widget you have added is not exactly below the `Text("A")`, there is something wrapping it up with a height of `100`, and that's your `Container` being drawn.